# Panelbar like in JotForm.com?

Tags: html, user-interface, css, jquery-ui-plugins

[Jotform.com](http://www.jotform.com) uses a nice panel bar, the navigation system in the left side. It looks polished and is rich in functionality. The items have a highlight and have help '?' functionality which display a preview upon hovering.

I don't know if they built it themselves. I was wondering if there's a jQuery plugin or UI
Framework that helps me build something very similar. I already have Telerik's controls however this one looks cooler.

Answer (score 0):

They probably did it with one of the JavaScript libraries they link to on the webpage.  The probably did it with [this](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) one?

Edit:  I was incorrect on closer inspection is is [this file](http://d3mc0rm5ezl95j.cloudfront.net/3.0.1687/min/minify_e1a5f675d13e8520ced10f8e6714f386.gz) that is used when the side panel is used, but I cannot find the library that it came from.

Perhaps you could just contact them and ask?